# Converting UTF-16LE to UTF-8 gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, gcloud

I'm working on auto deploy to google cloud with gitlab ci
use service json key to authenticate. I got stuck at when use echo command to create new json file which is UTF-16LE format but authentication needs UTF-8 no BOM to access.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```html
image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine

deploy_in_appengine:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - gcloud
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - golang-api-gitlab-deploy
  script:
    - echo $SERVICE_ACCOUNT > /tmp/gcloud-key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/gcloud-key.json
    - gcloud app deploy

after_script:
  - rm -f /tmp/gcloud-key.json
```

Comment: hey @QuangMinh, can you post the error message that you are receiving. also please edit read this information for future questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could change the charset used by the shell session inside the image [as shown here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/14983). However it is probably easier and more efficent to just use [iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv).

Your echo statement would look something like this:

```
echo "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT" | iconv --from-code=utf-16le --to-code=utf-8 --output=/tmp/gcloud-key.json
```